# oracle-java7-installer not installing on PowerBook G4 running Debian

Tags: java, linux, debian, java-7

I am running debian on this older G4 and having a problem installing Java. After searching on Google, I have only been finding issues with other linux distros, mostly ubuntu. I followed the instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/179266/187608) (which are pretty much the same as on all forums) but still getting the error below. So I am thinking that I just must be missing something else?

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  icedtea-netx-common libatk-wrapper-java libatk-wrapper-java-jni libice-dev
  libpthread-stubs0 libpthread-stubs0-dev libsm-dev libx11-dev libx11-doc
  libxau-dev libxcb1-dev libxdmcp-dev libxt-dev tzdata-java x11proto-core-dev
  x11proto-input-dev x11proto-kb-dev xorg-sgml-doctools xtrans-dev
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
Suggested packages:
  visualvm ttf-baekmuk ttf-unfonts ttf-unfonts-core ttf-kochi-gothic
  ttf-sazanami-gothic ttf-kochi-mincho ttf-sazanami-mincho ttf-arphic-uming
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  oracle-java7-installer
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/18.5 kB of archives.
After this operation, 111 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Preconfiguring packages ...
Please report to author unsupported platform 'ppc'.
Proceeding without web browser plugin support
Selecting previously unselected package oracle-java7-installer.
(Reading database ... 133336 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking oracle-java7-installer (from .../oracle-java7-installer_7u45-0~webupd8~6_all.deb) ...
Please report to author unsupported platform 'ppc'.
Proceeding without web browser plugin support
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info ...
Setting up oracle-java7-installer (7u45-0~webupd8~6) ...
Please report to author unsupported platform 'ppc'.
Proceeding without web browser plugin support
Please report to author unsupported platform 'ppc'.
Proceeding without web browser plugin support
Downloading Oracle Java 7...
--2014-01-05 12:35:22--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u45-b18/jdk-7u45-linux-.tar.gz
Resolving download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)... 165.254.157.186, 165.254.157.161
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|165.254.157.186|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u45-b18/jdk-7u45-linux-.tar.gz [following]
--2014-01-05 12:35:22--  https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u45-b18/jdk-7u45-linux-.tar.gz
Resolving edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)... 23.72.102.140
Connecting to edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)|23.72.102.140|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u45-b18/jdk-7u45-linux-.tar.gz?AuthParam=1388954247_1ac88f4b088d579770b3688a530d3ce9 [following]
--2014-01-05 12:35:27--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u45-b18/jdk-7u45-linux-.tar.gz?AuthParam=1388954247_1ac88f4b088d579770b3688a530d3ce9
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|165.254.157.186|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2014-01-05 12:35:27 ERROR 404: Not Found.

download failed
Oracle JDK 7 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing oracle-java7-installer (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java7-installer
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Hint: `unsupported platform 'ppc'`

Comment: @MattBall I googled that term and it led me [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html) but I already tried that solution as well. This is just my second day with Debian, so I would appreciate any other tips, thanks.

Comment: The error message suggests that the PPC architecture is unsupported. Consider that you might have to build from source yourself.

Answer (score 1):

If you actually are on a G4 then you have a PPC CPU.  So an X86 installer installer is not going to work.  The errors "unsupported platform 'ppc'" and "ERROR 404 " tell the story here.  There is not a Java7 PPC version available in the repository you are connecting to.  I am not sure if Oracle makes any PPC versions of the JVM for version 7 or not.

Specially JVM builds like that where generally things you had to compile your self back when Sun distributed Java.  Not sure if Oracle will let you compile your own JVM's any more.

Comment: Thank you for your input. would you know how to get java running on this type of machine?

Comment: Really the answer is I wouldn't.  Even if you do get a JVM running a CPU that old is not likely to do well with any modern software on it.  If you want to try As I said you will probably need to compile your own JVM if Oracle still allows that.  You might look into running a much older version of Java.  I am not sure what version of Java Macs where on before Apple switched to x86 CPU's

Answer (score 0):

PPC machines can run java up to version 5 (provided by Apple itself, in case of OSX Users).
In order to have a recent versions richer in features, you must point to [OpenJDK](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/OpenJDK/Darwin9Build) or [SoyLatte](http://www.bikemonkey.org/soylatte/). Current links are oriented for OS X Users, but both can be compiled on Debian.